# How to get Value from List<Bean> object in Jquery using Spring?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, spring

In my Spring Application have one Bean..

```
    public class SampleBean{
      private String id;
      private String name;
      private String marks;
      --------
      --------
}
```

And my Another Service bean Crating Property like..

```
List<SampleBean> list = new Array<SampleBean>();
//Setter and getters
```

And in my Controller class Set some values to `list`

And now my jsp i'm getting these values using Jquery..

```
<c:set var="modalAttributeName"value="MODEL1" />
<c:set var="modalAttribute"value="${requestScope[modalAttributeName]}" />
  <form:select class="select_box" path="country" id="country">
     <form:options items="${modalAttribute.list}" />
  </form:select>
```

It is showing entire Bean name like `SampleBean@0`

But i want in this Select box only `SampleBean` class `name` only..

So how to Display name using Jquery?

```
EDIT
```

i'm trying like this but empty box showing..

```
     <form:select class="select_box" path="country" id="country">
        <c:forEach items="${modalAttribute.list}" var="result">
            <form:options item="${result.name}" />
        </c:forEach>
    </form:select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this list to your model attribute map. I assume you already have a model map passed into your controller method. So for example:

```
model.put("list", list);
```

If you don't have the model map passed to your method, then just another parameter: `Map<String, Object> model`.

Then in your JSP:

```
 <form:select class="select_box" path="country" id="country">
    <c:forEach items="${list}" var="result">
        <form:option value="${result.name}">
            <c:out value="${result.name}"/>
        </form:option>
    </c:forEach>
</form:select>
```

Answer (score 0):

a possible sulition can be render the list as JSOn from controler and catch it in a java script code making an ajax call , thus its easier to use in jquery