# Iterating through a bean list and validate the data in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, jquery-plugins

My form contains input fields which will be validated against minimum and maximum values while submitting.The input fields will be displayed on the screen using list iteration.

```
<c:forEach var="Item" items="${listBean.nameList}" varStatus="status">
    <input type="number"name="nameList<c:outvalue='[${status.index}]'/>.initialWeight" onchange="checkOnChange(this,'<c:out value='${Item.personId}'/>','<c:out value='${Item.minWeight}'/>','<c:out value='${Item.maxWeight}'/>','<c:out value='[${status.index}]'/>')">
        <br><br>
    <input type="number" name="nameList<c:out value='[${status.index}]'/>.finalWeight" onchange="checkOnChange(this,'<c:out value='${Item.personId}'/>','<c:out value='${Item.minWeight}'/>','<c:out value='${Item.maxWeight}'/>','<c:out value='[${status.index}]'/>')">
        <br><br>
    <input type="text" class="formtext" name="nameList<c:out value='[${status.index}]'/>.Reason" id ="reason<c:out value='[${status.index}]'/>" value="" maxlength="255" >
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />

 </c:forEach>
```

So while submitting the form , i have all the user entered values which will be stored in the bean and also the min/ max values.i need to validate the form and prevent the user from submitting the form if any of the entered value is not within the min / max values.

So i am a bit of confused on how to do this in Java script ?

thanks for your suggestions and time ..

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jaggs/ehehjxbp/8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say give an `id`

```
<form id="frmDetails">
    <c:forEach var="Item" items="${listBean.nameList}" varStatus="status">
        <input type="number"name="nameList<c:outvalue='[${status.index}]'/>.initialWeight" onchange="checkOnChange(this,'<c:out value='${Item.personId}'/>','<c:out value='${Item.minWeight}'/>','<c:out value='${Item.maxWeight}'/>','<c:out value='[${status.index}]'/>')">
            <br><br>
        <input type="number" name="nameList<c:out value='[${status.index}]'/>.finalWeight" onchange="checkOnChange(this,'<c:out value='${Item.personId}'/>','<c:out value='${Item.minWeight}'/>','<c:out value='${Item.maxWeight}'/>','<c:out value='[${status.index}]'/>')">
            <br><br>
        <input type="text" class="formtext" name="nameList<c:out value='[${status.index}]'/>.Reason" id ="reason<c:out value='[${status.index}]'/>" value="" maxlength="255" >
            <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />

     </c:forEach>
</form>
```

Below will the form submit function

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#frmDetails").on("submit",function(e){
var valid=true;
e.preventDefault();
var inputs=$(this).children('input');
$.each('input',function(index,value){
   if($(this).val()=="")//blank validation
   {
          valid=false;
   }
});
if(valid)
{
//post the form
}

$("#frmDetails").unbind("submit"); //To prevent the form from getting submitted 
});

</script>
```

Comment: You should use `e.preventDefault()` only when the form is not valid.

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao Thanks for your reply.But in my case i need to pass the min and maximum values stored in the bean to the jquery function so that it can be validated.But your answer merely checks for blank values

Comment: Actually I've no experience or better to say do not know about this bean list, so I just gave you a basic idea of how you can validate... :) Anyhow **[this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358112/how-to-get-value-from-listbean-object-in-jquery-using-spring)** might be helpful.. :)